# Issue while connecting AWS windows system using ubuntu(16.04) client

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to connect using

xfreerdp  /u: "Administrator" /v:ipaddress:3389 getting following issue
[image]

Comment: there is also `rdesktop` client for rdp. Maybe worth trying?

Comment: Ok thanks, I tried with Remmina. It worked